# Datastream can not connect to Cloud SQL with private IP using private connectivity

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-datastream

My Datastream is not able to connect to Cloud SQL (with private IP) using a private connectivity.

I have setup my cloud SQL (Postgres) for replication as it is already streaming events for debezium.

I have created a private connectivity in my VPC and filled the connection profile using my database private IP. Is there anything I am missing ?
Here the error I am receiving:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must use a TCP proxy in your VPC. Follow that [documentation for AlloyDB](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-postgresql-database#alloydbforpostgresql), it's pretty similar

Comment: any reason why a simple VPC peering not working ?

Comment: The peering between what and what?

Comment: Got the answer at that link https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/private-connectivity I thought I could link directly the private SQL and datastream VPC but this is actually not possible. Thanks for the help!